# Referencing data in sets of sets

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions, tuples

Given a data set how to assign definitions to the subsets. For
instance given the data

```
data = {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}
```

if {0, 1, 1} is SetA and {1, 1, 0} is SetB the result would be data={SetA, SetA, SetA, SetB, SetA}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
rules = {{0, 1, 1} -> setA, {1, 1, 0} -> setB};

data /. rules
```

> ```
> {setA, setA, setB, setA, setB}
> ```

Alternatively, define a function that evaluates to `setA` for `{0,1,1}` and to `setB` for `{1,1,0}` and map it on `data`:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[{0, 1, 1}] = setA;
f[{1, 1, 0}] = setB;

f /@ data
```

> ```
> {setA, setA, setB, setA, setB}
> ```